# How to correctly use lodash pick method

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm attempting to use underscore to filter out certain properties of an object. The beginning of the following code works as expected, but `.pick` is not working. I'm aiming to limit the properties of the returned object to those strings listed in the `.pick` method.

```
var result = _.chain(data)
  .each(function(item) {
    item.answers = [];
    _.each(data, function(object) {
      if (item.id === object.id) {
        item.answers.push({
          id: object.answer_id,
          email: object.answer_email,
          date: object.answer_date
        });
      }
    });
    item = _.pick(item,
      'id',
      'owner_id',
      'url',
      'enabled',
      'review_date',
      'answers'
    );
  })
  .uniq(function(item) {
    return item.id;
  })
  .value();
```

The array I start with, 'data', looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: '8ffdf27b-5a90-478a-b263-dhhdhdhhdhd',
    answer_date: Fri Oct 30 2015 14:35:07 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    answer_id: 1,
    answer_email: 'test@example.com',
    owner_id: 5,
    url: 'media/5-4a3640ac-ec13-fhhfh-ac0a-fhjhdhhdhd.jpg',
    enabled: false,
    review_date: Sun Nov 01 2015 13:57:32 GMT-0500 (EST)
  }, ...
]
```

The returned array 'should' look like so:

```
[
  {
    id: '8ffdf27b-5a90-478a-b263-dhhdhdhhdhd',
    owner_id: 5,
    url: 'media/5-4a3640ac-ec13-fhhfh-ac0a-fhjhdhhdhd.jpg',
    enabled: false,
    review_date: Sun Nov 01 2015 13:57:32 GMT-0500 (EST),
    answers: [{...}, {...}]
  }, ...
]
```

but instead currently looks like this:

```
[
  {
    id: '8ffdf27b-5a90-478a-b263-dhhdhdhhdhd',
    answer_date: Fri Oct 30 2015 14:35:07 GMT-0400 (EDT),
    answer_id: 1,
    answer_email: 'test@example.com',
    owner_id: 5,
    url: 'media/5-4a3640ac-ec13-fhhfh-ac0a-fhjhdhhdhd.jpg',
    enabled: false,
    review_date: Sun Nov 01 2015 13:57:32 GMT-0500 (EST),
    answers: [{...}, {...}]
  }, ...
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`map()`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) instead of `each()` to change your array (note that you have to return the modified item in the map function):

```
var result = _.chain(data)
.map(function (item) {
  item.answers = [];
  _.each(data, function (object) {
    if (item.id === object.id) {
      item.answers.push({
        id: object.answer_id,
        email: object.answer_email,
        date: object.answer_date
      });
    }
  });
  item = _.pick(item,
    'id',
    'owner_id',
    'url',
    'enabled',
    'review_date',
    'answers'
  );
  return item;
})
.uniq(function (item) {
  return item.id;
})
.value();
```